# How does this compressor move when gas is compressed?

Tags: classical-mechanics, ideal-gas

[image]

A hypothetical gas compressor consists of two pistons that move towards each other at the same speed. When the pistons move, the local pressure p1 increases while local pressure p2 increases due to mass flowing from p1 to p2. Hence p1 and p2 do not increase simultaneously but the increase of p2 "lags" the increase of p1. As long as a pressure difference exists, the compressor accelerates to the left. When the pressures are equal, the compressor stops accelerating and has a final velocity (friction neglected).

Now the question: Is this final velocity dependent upon the speed at which the pistons move? My intuition says that the slower the pistons move, the slower the final velocity of the compressor but since it is non-trivial I could be completely wrong.

What do you say?

Comment: Unless you add e.g. a barrier with a small hole between p1 and p2, the changes in p1 and p2 can be considered simultaneous (or, if you want to describe the dynamics, more complicated than just two numbers p1 and p2). Also, where is the left-moving part in your image?

Comment: @Solarflare: The whole machine should move to the left when p1>p2. Although the changes in p1 and p2 can be considered to be simultaneous for the sake of simplicity; in reality p2 lags p1.

Comment: How is the whole machine moving? Currently it is not. Also, during the time that "p2 lags p1", there is no value for p1 or p2 (that is what I meant with dynamics), unless it has dimensions of like e.g. the earths athmosphere. But that is not the important point I guess, and does not have an effect on your question. But I still don't see why you think the machine moves. Could you draw some forces into your image? You need net forces to make your body move. You could e.g. move the wall on the right side of p2, or open it there to move the whole machine (like releasing air out of a balloon).